# Eclipse Maven - No 'package' option

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to use Maven in Eclipse, and I am trying to package my project. I right click on My **pom.xml**, I go to **Run as**, but there is no "**Maven Package**" option there.

*This is how it looks:*

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the `Maven install` it should also do the packaging. You will find the resulting artifacts in the directory called `target`.

If you want to run only mvn package, I believe you need to select the option number "3 Maven build ..."

Comment: So the "Maven package" option is not even supposed to be there?

Comment: Right, to be honest I use Maven only from command line and the package phase is not so common. Most of the times you just do `mvn install`, that will do code generation (if there is any), the packaging, runs the tests, etc. and installs the artifact to your local maven repository so that other projects can depend on it.